# Downloading .csv file from public folder says failed no file

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to set a simple href link to download a .csv file from my public folder but when clicking it just says 'Failed - No File', yet I know all the other paths to my public folder work because all the images load. I feel like im missing something i dont know about. I have set the public folder like so:

```
set :public_folder, File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/public"
```

and the href is as follows:

```
<a href="/csv_file/<%=@file.name%>" download="updated_<%=@file.name%>" style="text-align: center;" download>Download</a>
```

I hope this is enough information. Thanks

Comment: Does the generated href match what you expect it to be? You are also not using /public in your route.

Comment: yes, the text is correct, the downloadedfile name(although no file) is correct, and the path displayed is correct when hovering over the link.

Comment: What is the generated HTML? Is `@file.name` valid? Images loading doesn't tell us much unless you're using variables to define their names too.  Please read "[mcve]" and give us a bit more detail.

Comment: Hi, sorry the app is pretty light weight any way, it just updates an image with a watermark and csv file with the image url on, i just dont understand why it wont work. its here https://github.com/wrumble/SilkFredApp on the test branch

Answer (score 0):

Example project structure.

```
$ tree
.
├── app.rb
├── Gemfile
├── public
│   └── lorem.csv
└── views
    └── index.erb
```

I've set up project omitting local variables (in your case @file etc.)

```
#app.rb
require 'sinatra'

set :public_folder, File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/public"

get '/' do
  erb :index
end
```

view file

```
#index.erb
<a href="/lorem.csv" style="text-align: center;" download>Download</a>
```

When clicking on download link, what I get is,

[image]

What you should do is, to check the final url on your view. Also please share route block.

Answer (score -1):

File.dirname(__FILE__) returns the relative path. Try using File.expand_path(__FILE__) instead.

Comment: I  tried your suggestion but it gives same result.  Thanks tho

Comment: Switching from a relative path to a full path shouldn't make a difference, especially when dealing with serving files.